# creating a network between localhost and virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, routing, administration

Ok I have this machine of mine in a network (in an external domain) and I would like to create in it a virtual machine, which should be able to connect and communnicate with the host (main machine) and in the meanwhile allowing to the host to connect in its own network.

Let's suppose the main machine ip is 192.168.1.2 and its network gateway is 192.168.1.1 (and subnet mask 255.255.255.0);
let's suppose I can't assign another ip of this subnet at the virtual machine host (so I can't assign a 192.168.1.3 with gateway 192.168.1.1) because there's (or there could be) a 192.168.1.3 in the network (which I can't manage);
but I would like the 192.168.1.2 machine to communicate with 192.168.1.1 network and in the meanwhile the virtual machine itself.
How should I (if possible) configurate the virtual machine in order to be viewed only by the host and not to duplicate the ip in the network? Is there a way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow the VM to access only the host machine, you can create a virtual ethernet interface to use a new subnet (e.g. 169.254.128.1 for the host and 169.254.128.2 for the VM). In Virtualbox this is known as Host-Only Networking. If you need the VM to have access to the internet via the host's 192.168.1.2 interface you'll need to configure Network Address Translation (NAT), which forwards the traffic between the host's ethernet adapter and the VMs.

These settings can be found in the GUI under Settings -> Network -> Attached to.